# Which side of the Zagreb - Ljubljana Train has more scenic views?

Tags: trains, croatia, vantage-points, slovenia, scenic-routes

Going to Ljubljana from Zagreb by train soon. The Seat61 describes the ride:

> There are several trains every day linking Zagreb & Ljubljana, journey
>   time 2h28.  It's a lovely scenic train ride through the hills along
>   the beautiful River Sava.

Is there a side of train that affords better views?

*Some scenic routes I've been on in other contents are only scenic from one side as the train might follow the base of a cliff. Some passengers see a rock wall the whole way and others see valleys, rivers, towns, etc*

Comment: For sure on top of the ceiling..

Comment: Do Europe trains allow travelers on the roof? I did it in South America, it gives very nice views. I haven't travel by train in Europe for over 30 years but I don't remember seeing that.

Comment: of course not, it is just one of my bad jokes.. Gayot Fow told me to stop making jokes here but I can't ;)

Comment: @NeAnDerthal, I made a "spirited suggestion", not 'told'

Comment: Sit on the left side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did that train ride a few years ago and remember sitting on the right side of the train. The River was on the right side for most of the time as well.

We were in a compartment and we could always go outside to stand in the corridor to look out on the left side as well. I don't remember it being a very narrow valley, so I think you have some views on both sides.

Also I don't think the whole two and a half hours were super special.

**Edit:** I just realized you are going from Zagreb to Ljubljana, I went the other way, so in that case sit on the left side of the train.

Comment: +1, agree that left is better.   It's a question that sits on the border of opinion-based.  But the left side has a slight advantage.

Comment: Indeed, the left side was much nicer. Just an oddity though, some train cars had all the seats on the left, others on the right, so we have to make sure to choose the right car.

Comment: It's pretty normal to have some cars with the compartments on the right and others on the left. When the train goes back to Zagreb the other cars with the seats on the right will be the better ones.